# Using same download works with browser but not wget or curl

Tags: linux, image, curl, wget

I am trying to download an image from the [link](https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500)  found in Google. When using `Save Image As..` within the browser the image is downloaded successfully, but one of the:

```
wget -O image.jpeg https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
# or
curl -L https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500 -o
```

Gives an output very similar to Hebrew...

[image: Jebrish]

What is the correct way to download the same image using terminal tools?

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to quote a URL in single quotes (as usual :))

Comment: surprisingly this worked